# getting the name of a key of an object in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I hopefully have a very simple question but if I have the code

```
console.log("my args", args);
```

and the result that comes back is

```
Object { pageList1=null}
```

how do i get the name pageList1

it doesnt matter that this is null i just need the name pageList1..

this is what i have tried

```
parse: function (result, args) {
    var myKey = Object.keys(args);

    return result.data.myKey;
}
```

ok so using on of the answers i updated the code to be

```
parse: function (result, args) {

    for (variable in args) {

        return result.data.variable;
    }

}
```

but that doesnt like just the name variable as thats not in the JSON structure..

OK so the answer was

```
parse: function (result, args) {

    var pageListVariable = Object.keys(args)[0];

    return result.data[pageListVariable];
}
```

when needing to change the call of the json the . needs to be replaced with []

Comment: `["pageList1"][0] -> "pageList1"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Object.keys` is a fine way to access the keys of an object, but it does give you *all* keys, in an array of strings. Incidentally, your object happens to have only one key, but the function still yields an array, albeit of one string. (In fact, it would be terribly inconvenient if it treated single-key objects as a special case and yielded only a string; you would always have to type-check before iterating over the result).

If, in your specific scenario, you *know* there will always be only one key, it's perfectly fine to go ahead and access that by index immediately `Object.keys(args)[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

you should use [for in](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in).

```
for (variable in object) {
  console.log(variable)
}
```

Comment: thanks.. added your code above but one last litle justion there also

Comment: The closest equivalence of `Object.keys` is a `for ... in` paired with a `hasOwnProperty` condition. On its own, the two yield different results, which may cause a problem if there are any properties added to `Object.prototype` elsewhere in the code.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this will help:

```
var keys = [];
for (x in args) {
  console.log("Key=>" + x +", val="+args[x]);
  keys.push (x); //where x is the key
}
alert(keys);
```